# Recommendation "use MySQL for current tables and use MongoDB for a new table that can be huge"

Tags: mysql, mongodb, grails, nosql

I am using a MySQL database and I have a very big table which could reach 100,000,000 rows within a year. Unfortunately, it is getting more and more slow.

What is the best solution to adopt in that case? Could NoSQL be a solution?

What about using MySQL and MongoDB in the same project? That way, we would not alter the previous structure of database and use MongoDB for only this big table.

Comment: Are you planning to do search on that specific table?

Comment: Yes, even I applied indexing in this table @BuhakeSindi

Comment: So, all the table columns that you're searching on are indexed?

Comment: In fact, i want to store information that concerns longitude and latitude of users. User' s position can be updated more than 100 times per day
so the table will be huge because i want to keep all the history of the previous year.
For your information, i will access the table in read mode also. @BuhakeSindi

Comment: If you only need the most recent coordinates for your main query, then create 2 tables: one with the current position, and one with the position history. Maybe it would be useful to show us your DB structure and the slow query. Doing computations on 100.000.000 documents using MongoDB *must not* be faster, if you don't use sharding. It really depends on your query and if you can use more than 1 server for the database. If you've got a lot of JOINs MongoDB can speed things up on a single machine. But as stated above: Show us your data structure and query. Maybe this can be optimized.

Comment: The table which contains the position history has this structure : longitude(Float), latitude(Float), address(String), date(Date), user_id (Long).
The query is without JOIN and will be like this: SELECT longitude, latitude, address, date FROM Table WHERE user_id = value  limit 200;
The columns are indexed.
How i can optimize this query? 
If i suppose that i have a sufficient disk space, what are the possible other problems of performance that i might face using MYSQL database with 
this structure and query? @BenjaminM

Comment: For this query you only need an index on `user_id`. Additionally you should not use `limit` without an `order by` because there's no guaranteed order if you don't use `order by`. Maybe put some timestamp in your rows. Then of course you should have a compound index on `user_id` + `myTimestamp`. But even with the query you have shown, with an index on `user_id` and limit 200, this should get executed in a few milliseconds. `...` so, next step would be: show us an `EXPLAIN` (and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`) of your query, so we can see what's really going on, which indexes are used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to summarize your **requirement:**

1. Huge data size with more than 100,000,000 entries.
2. Retrieval is against a particular user and should be fast.
3. Multiple entries exist against single user.

Any Key/Value based NoSQL solution can work here e.g. Redis, Aerospike, etc for below mentioned reasons:

1. Can easily store this much amount of data and in-built support for data distribution across nodes.
2. Most use hashing and that is the fastest way of querying when the data size becomes huge.
3. User can be kept as Record key and its history as value.

Aerospike's [LDT](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/ldt.html) can come quite handy here where each user history can be mapped to one entry in Large List of Aerospike and can be retrieved at once.

Hope it helps.